# How to determine an object's class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

How to determine an object's class in Java?

Class B and class C extend class A. This is a method implementation in class D called dmethod(object of  B or C)
,it except a single parameter that can be object of B or C.

The calling methods can be

1. dmethod(B object)
2. dmethod(C object)

How to write code for this scenario?

Comment: *Why* are you wanting to do this? This is nearly always a bad practice that indicates the code should be reworked.

Comment: In an existing application, I am having a filtration method (that is dmethod(String val, Object B). It is doing something kind of filtration using the Object B contents. But, now I need same kind filtration using Object C content. I like to do it in minimal code change and also lesser impact. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, the thing that you're needing to do should be in an overridden method that each class implements according to its needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine an object's class, start with:

```
Object.getClass()
```

and go from there.

Once you have actual `Class` object for your particular object you can interrogate [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for information like its name and so on.

For part (2) of your question, if both B and C extend A, then you can define `dmethod()` like this:

```
dmethod(A a)
```

The method can then act on anything that is common to both B and C, ie. in their superclass (A). If you need something specific to B or C, you could downcast 'a' to B or C (check using instanceof to see what the type of 'a' is).

You can define two versions of dmethod() as per your question, one that takes in a B and one that take in a C. Overloading supports this.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Could you please explain little more. What will be the method implementation structure?

Comment: @Rems what are you trying to achieve exactly? And what do you mean by structure?

Comment: I understood your solution. This is my requirement, in an existing application, I am having a filtration method (that is dmethod(String val, Object B). It is doing some kind of filtration using the Object B contents. But, now I need same kind filtration using Object C content. I like to do it in minimal code change and also with lesser impact. Is there any better way to do this? Do the suggested solution is a good practice?

Comment: Hard to know without the specifics. But dmethod(String, C) is minimal and should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Inside **dmethod(Object o)**,

use:

```
if(o instanceof B) {
     // ...
}
else if( o instanceof C) {
     // ...
}
```

to find out if the argument passed in is a B object or C object?

More on [instanceof](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm).